# How to create a 2D matrix with for loop iterating across a struct

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, for-loop, matrix

In a directory I have a collection of 20 files. I want to:

- iterate a loop across those 20 files,
- extract `x` and `y` data from them and
- place those data in a 2D matrix that is created within the loop

Note below that `files'` is a 20x1 struct and `file` is a 1x1 struct.

I'm unsure how to build the 2-dimenstional matrix A inside such a loop.

I've tried something like

```
files = dir('./cases/*.dcm');

for file = files'

    [data extraction here, creating vars x and y]

    for k = 1:length(files')
        A(k,:) =  (x:y);
    end
end
```

but I get

```
Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: *Any idea what I'm doing wrong?*, Nope, as I can't see the sizes of all things from here. This is however one of the most clear error messages MATLAB can throw at you, meaning your RHS has a different number of elements than the LHS. Check the sizes of all things

Comment: Plus it's weird to iterate twice on the same stuff

Comment: yes i agree with both of you, but can you give me any pointer on how one would go about creating a 2D matrix in this situation? I'll be glad to provide any specific info you need, I just don't know where to begin.

Comment: What do your files contain exactly? What are the sizes of x and y?

Comment: files are Dicom images (grayscale), from which I extract gray level values. X and Y are binary variables, which will be different for each file

Comment: So X and Y will be 2-dimensionnal matrices already right? Or are `x` and `y` ony the minimum and maximum levels of gray for this specific image?

Comment: if you take the first iteration of the loop, example values would be X=0 and Y=1. Next iteration, X=1 and Y=1, and so on. What I want is to create matrix A that contains these values, so at the end I'd have something like A = [0,1;1,1;0,0 etc]

Comment: Can X=1 and Y=0 possibly happen?

Comment: yes X=1 and Y=0 can happen

Comment: Are you saying that `X` and `Y` are just one number each? If so try `files = dir('./cases/*.dcm');for k = numel(files);file = files(k);[data extraction here, creating vars x and y];A(k,:) =  [x,y];end`.

Comment: Is it intended that you have a nested loop inside your main loop? If this code was runnable, it would fill A with the last x and y only

Comment: Maybe try to stock your variables in cells rather than a matrix (`A{k} = (x:y)`)

Comment: Thanks @JensBoldsen that addresses my problem and solved the issue. Please feel free to post as answer and I'll select it. Note a minor correction here `for k = 1:numel(files)` -- the `1:` is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
files = dir('./cases/*.dcm');
for k = 1:numel(files)
    file = files(k);
    %[data extraction here, creating vars x and y];
    A(k,:) = [x,y];
end
```

You might also want to add an initialization before the loop like:

```
A = zeros(numel(files),2);
```